# When to embed documents in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to best design Mongo DB schemas. The Mongo DB documentation recommends relying heavily on embedded documents for improved querying, but I'm wondering if my use case actually justifies referenced documents.

A very basic version of my current schema is basically:
(Apologies for the psuedo-format, I'm not sure how to express Mongo schemas)

```
users {
  email (string)
}

games {
  user (reference user document)
  date_started (timestamp)
  date_finished (timestamp)
  mode (string)
  score: {
    total_points (integer)
    time_elapsed (integer)
  }
}
```

Games are short (about 60 seconds long) and I expect a lot of concurrent writes to be taking place.

At some point, I'm going to want to calculate a high score list, and possibly in a segregated fashion (e.g., high score list for a particular game.mode or date)

Is embedded documents the best approach here? Or is this truly a problem that relations solves better? How would these use cases best be  solved in Mongo DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ... is this truly a problem that relations solves better?

The key here is less about *"is this a relation?"* and more about *"how am I going to access this?"*

MongoDB is not "anti-reference". MongoDB does ***not*** have the benefits of joins, but it ***does*** have the benefit of embedded documents.

As long as you understand these trade-offs then it's perfectly fair to use references in MongoDB. It's really about how you plan to query these objects.

> Is embedded documents the best approach here?

Maybe. Some things to consider.

- Do `games` have value outside of the context of the `user`?
- How many `games` will a single `user` have?
- Is `games` transactional in nature?
- How are you going to access `games`? Do you always need all of a user's games?

If you're planning to build leaderboards and a user can generate hundreds of game documents, then it's probably fair to have games in their own collection. Storing ten thousand instances of "game" inside of each users isn't particularly useful.

But depending on your answers to the above, you could really go either way. As the litmus test, I would try running some Map / Reduce jobs (*i.e. build a simple leaderboard*) to see how you feel about the structure of your data.

Comment: The first two phrases of your answer are really a great way of explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a relation here? If the 'email' is the only user property than denormalization and using an embedded document would be perfectly fine. If the user object contains other information I would go for a reference.

Comment: It does contain other information -- a lot more actually. I cut it out for the sake of keeping my question short -- sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should to use "entity-object" and "object-value" definitions from [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design). For entity use reference,but for "object-value" use embed document.
Also you can use denormalization of your object. i mean that you can duplicate your data. e.g.

```
// root document    
game
    {
        //duplicate part that you need of root user
        user: { FirstName: "Some name", Id: "some ID"}
    } 
// root document 
user
   {
      Id:"ID",
      FirstName:"someName",
      LastName:"last name",
      ...
   }
```