# In a Mongo Schema, is there a performance difference when considering to Link or to Embed?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am considering two different schemas for a mongo reporting layer of a web application built on SAP and Salesforce Data. It appears on first look (although the requirements are not set) we will be analyzing the data on a `Customer` and also on `Invoice`s (as in not necessarily through the customer itself). I am left with the decision to Link to `Invoice`s in the `Customer` or to embed the `Invoice`s in the customer. Like so:

### Linked/Referenced Example

**Customer:**

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'John Doe',
 invoices: [1,2,3]
}
```

**Invoice:**

```
{
 id: 1,
 customer_id: 1
}
```

### Embedded Example

**Customer:**

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'John Doe',
 invoices: [{id: 1, customer_id:2, amount: 100}]
}
```

### The Question

My dataset will be large, leaving a customer with hundreds of thousands of invoices and invoice line items. Is it always the case that linking or embedding will be more performant than the ulterior option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to embed documents in Mongo DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073979/when-to-embed-documents-in-mongo-db)

Comment: I would present your real use case before you get closed as a duplicate. The generic question has been asked many times, and generic questions do not provide the answers you need for your specific situation.

Comment: My question isn't around best schema for accessing the data. Its a question of performance on a larger data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hundreds of thousands" sounds like it might even break the mongodb document size limit, which speaks for the linking option.

A key question is whether you always need all invoice data when accessing a customer and whether you ever need to delete these invoices. If you always need all the data and you hardly ever need to modify it, embedding can be a bit faster. Essentially, you're saving a number of index lookups, but since those aren't expensive, the gain is small.

Performance-wise, the best approach is often a mixture, i.e. a number of documents each containing a number of invoices for a particular customer. That way, your objects aren't too small (i.e. little indexing, padding and serialization overhead) and not too large (little congestion, no long blocking operations). As usual, that's an ugly abstraction with little flexibility.

I'd go for the more flexible linking approach and only try to optimize it if it's really necessary.

Comment: Very interesting, this data will almost never be updated. It is simply for a historical reference and predictive api.